# grep for multiple strings in a single line

Tags: shell, unix, grep, pre-commit-hook

I need to check if any of the strings "Added/Changed/Fixed/Deleted" are in a commit log message. I am writing an svn precommit hook, and the expected commit comment should have one of these 4 strings in the message.

The code I am using is as below

```
REPOS=$1
TXN=$2

SVN="/usr/bin/svn";
SVNLOOK="/usr/bin/svnlook";

$SVNLOOK log "$REPOS" -t "$TXN" | \
grep "[a-zA-Z0-9]" > /dev/null

GREP_STATUS=$?
if [ $GREP_STATUS -ne 0 ]
then
  "${ECHO}" "No Log comments present" >> "${LOG}"
   echo "Your commit has been blocked because you didn't give any log message" 1>&2
   echo "Please write a log message describing the purpose of your changes and" 1>&2
   echo "then try committing again. -- Thank you" 1>&2
exit 1
fi
```

In the above code,

```
$SVNLOOK log "$REPOS" -t "$TXN"
```

will give me the commit message that the user has entered. Now I have to check for the presence of any of the strings "Added, Changed, Fixed, Deleted" in the message.
That is,

```
if (any of the above 4 strings are not present),
 exit 1
```

I tried with

```
$($SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | grep -q "Added\|Changed\|Fixed\|Deleted"|)
```

but it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" is not a very useful diagnostic, please provide a minimal example that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To used alternation you need `Extended Regexp`:

```
grep -qE 'Added|Changed|Fixed|Deleted'
```

Or:

```
egrep -q 'Added|Changed|Fixed|Deleted'
```

Comment: On my RHEL machine, the `-q` option suppresses normal output of the command, so this option should be omitted.

Answer (score 12):

Use `grep -e` option (multiple times) like this:

```
grep -e Added -e Changed -e Fixed -e Deleted
```

otherwise go to the regex route:

```
grep --regexp=Added|Changed|Fixed|Deleted
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the backslashes and use `egrep` I also recommend `-i` for case insensitive matching:

```
egrep -q -i "added|changed|fixed|deleted"
```

Comment: `-e` != `-E` and doing a case insensitive match may produce false positives.

Comment: On my RHEL machine, `-q` (the "quiet" flag) suppresses the output of `egrep`, so nothing prints...

Comment: Yes, @Kevin, that's what the OP tries to do with 3 lines (grep to /dev/null, save $? in GREP_STATUS, then using it in if). He could use the above command directly in the if.